# Singular fits in simulation power analysis

Tags: r, mixed-model, statistical-power

We have fitted a linear mixed model to the data of a split-plot design with 2 factors (between: `condition.t` - 3 levels; within: `SM.blockDiff` - 2 levels). As there were in total 6 measurements per person (person ID: `VP`), we also wanted to include a time polynomial time factor (`blockID.c`).

The model was fitted in `R` using the `mixed` method from the package `afex` which is essentially a wrapper around `lmerTest`/`lmer`. This fit worked without problems or warnings.

```
model <- mixed(quest ~ factor(blockID.c)  * condition.t * SM.blockDiff + (poly(blockID.c, 4)|VP), data=df)
```

We now wanted to perform a post-hoc power-analysis on the interaction term of `condition.t * SM.blockDiff` using the `powerSim` method from the package `simr`.
This was done with the following call:

```
power <- powerSim(model$full_model, test = fcompare(~ condition.t+SM.blockDiff, "kr"), nsim=200)
```

During progression of the simulation multiple warnings about singular fits appeared and the print of this power calculation also lists that:

```
> power
Power for model comparison, (95% confidence interval):
      54.50% (47.33, 61.54)

Test: Kenward-Roger (package pbkrtest)
      Comparison to ~condition.t + SM.blockDiff + [re]

Based on 200 simulations, (165 warnings, 0 errors)
alpha = 0.05, nrow = 288

Time elapsed: 0 h 12 m 29 s

nb: result might be an observed power calculation
```

When calling the warnings from the result, these are full of messages like this:

```
> head(power$warnings)
    stage index                                                                         message
1 Testing     1                   Model failed to converge with 1 negative eigenvalue: -1.9e-01
2 Testing     2 Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00668068 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
3 Fitting     3  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.0053056 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
4 Testing     3                   Model failed to converge with 1 negative eigenvalue: -1.3e-01
5 Testing     4                   Model failed to converge with 1 negative eigenvalue: -9.7e-04
6 Fitting     5                   Model failed to converge with 1 negative eigenvalue: -4.9e-02
```

I know about "regular" singular fits in LMMs and how to interpret or avoid them, however I'm unsure what to make of them in this case.

**Do I need to worry about them or can I just ignore them and trust the results?**
This [official vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/simr/vignettes/fromscratch.html) also seems to have singular fits however does not mention them. Also the singular fits there don't seem to show up on the printed summary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I need to worry about them or can I just ignore them and trust the results?

Yes, you need to worry about them. Those don't look like singular fit warnings - more like convergence warnings. That is the models have not converged, unlike a singular fit where the model converges, usually to boundary on the parameter space such as a zero variance or +1 or -1 correlation.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I actually asked the package author about the problem and got confirmation that those warnings are rather serious: https://github.com/pitakakariki/simr/issues/169#issuecomment-654482182

Comment: Thanks for the link. That's pretty much what I thought !